# What connection expression do I need to set on the follow json data?

Tags: json, jasper-reports

I have a Report generated in Jaspersoft Studio and use a Dataadapter which is a JSON Rest Service.

**Everything works fine for simple values but now i have an array inside my json structure:**

```
  {
    ...
   "A": {
          "B": [
          {
            "C": "asdf"
          },
          {
            "C": "xyz"
          }
       ]
     },
... }
```

**In my Report I want to create a Table and List all Values of C in it. After creating the table and a Dataset my Report looks like this:**

```
<subDataset name="Dataset" uuid="e3a0dc52-fba1-48fe-a067-84fae6a3448c">
<property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.data.defaultdataadapter" value="Adapter"/>
<queryString language="json">
<![CDATA[A.B]]>
    </queryString>
    <field name="C" class="java.lang.String">
    <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.json.field.expression" value="C"/>
    <fieldDescription><![CDATA[C]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
</subDataset>
...
<jr:table xmlns:jr="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/components" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/components http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/components.xsd" whenNoDataType="AllSectionsNoDetail">
                <datasetRun subDataset="Dataset" uuid="d44a71a8-7a49-440a-abbe-056276894f5c">
                        <connectionExpression><![CDATA[$P{REPORT_CONNECTION}]]></connectionExpression></dataSourceExpression>
                </datasetRun>
                <jr:column width="200" uuid="22888b9f-4eff-483e-8d7c-d0d6748e8ce7">
                    <jr:tableHeader style="Table_TH" height="30"/>
                    <jr:tableFooter style="Table_TH" height="30"/>
                    <jr:columnHeader style="Table_CH" height="30"/>
                    <jr:columnFooter style="Table_CH" height="30"/>
                    <jr:detailCell style="Table_TD" height="30">
                        <textField>
                            <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="200" height="30" uuid="b7df3878-ef55-4a7b-b89b-4083da2d5297"/>
                            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{C}]]></textFieldExpression>
                        </textField>
                    </jr:detailCell>
                </jr:column>
            </jr:table>
```

But when I click on Preview i never get any data in my table?

I am pretty sure i have an issue with my connectionExpression but i can't find any clues in the documentation what the right Expression would be.

Answer (score 0):

The connectionexpression needs to be

```
((net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JsonDataSource)$P{REPORT_DATA_SOURCE}).subDataSource("A.B")
```

so the parameter for `subDataSource` needs to be the path to your array in your json structure.